# PHP - Download from URL and Upload via FTP

Tags: php, ftp, fopen, ftps

Slightly weird concept here... A client of ours wants data pushed to them over FTP/S

The idea is that we download one of our reports by downloading from a URL (a CSV File), then push this to the client over FTP/S. I know I can do this in bash scripts using wget & ftp - but need to add to this over a web interface so PHP is the best way forward.

As this is a background task I can extend time-outs etc.

I know also I can use fopen to download and save a file, then find it and upload it using the PHP FTP library. Just looking for a way to download using fopen, hold the data in memory to upload straight away.

Any help appreciated in advance!

Comment: Use the existing tools instead of writing your own. You can call them from PHP, too.

Comment: I don't think you can directly upload file directly from memory. You should save it to a local folder, then after successful upload; delete it.

Comment: @Arda, you thought wrong, but of course your second statement is a valid opinion, but it doesn't always apply.

Comment: @hakre, that is enough in some cases, but my experience says that there are many cases where the opposite is true.

Comment: @Peter: I think wrappers count as an existing tool :)

Comment: @hakre, ah yes, you're right, but that's not how I interpreted your comment.. :P I was thinking more along existing tool = bash/wget/ftp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To retrieve the data from the URL you have a few options. You say you want the data in memory only to push directly to the FTP host.

One approach (that I find the simplest to use, but lacking in terms of reliability and error handling) is `file_get_contents()`

Example:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/csvfile';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
```

Now you have your csv data in `$data`, over to how to push this to an ftp server.

Again the simplest way to do this is to use the builtin stream wrappers as used in the get example above. (Note however that this requires PHP 4.3.0)

Simply build up the connection string like this.

```
$protocol = 'ftps';
$hostname = 'ftp.domain.com';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$directory = '/pub';
$filename = 'filename.csv';
$connectionString = sprintf("%s://%s:%s@%s%s/%s",
    $protocol,$username,$hostname,
    $password,$directory,
    $filename);


file_put_contents($connectionString,$data);
```

Have a look at the [ftp wrappers manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php)

If this does not work there are other options.

You could use [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get the data and the [FTP Extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) to push it.

Comment: Cheers for this - I am tempted on thinking more about this to download, then re-upload just so that I can run some md5 checks on the file before and after upload to check integrity - However I am going to try implementing that with this code :)

Comment: you can do md5 checks in memory as well. Oh and if you plan on pushing to the same file each time, read the manual about overwriting it doesn't work without special settings.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid saving the file to disk and "to upload straight away" i.e. to start pushing to FTP as soon as the first chunk of Data is downloaded?

Try this:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php

You'll need an FTP server and client library which support resuming uploads

Comment: +1 That could probably work. Unless you want the md5 controls of course.